# How to SELECT from three different tables using multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
languages

id | tag   | region        | language
--   -----   -------------   --------
1    en-US   United States   English
2    es-ES   Spain           Spanish
...
```

```
modules

id | module
--   ------
1    header
2    main
3    footer
```

```
contents

id | language_id | module_id | content
--   -----------   ---------   -------
1    1             1           This is my header
2    1             3           This is my footer
3    2             1           Este es mi encabezado
```

I want to select all content for all of the expected modules, even if there's no `contents` record for that module, (notice I'm missing a "main" module) so I've written:

```
SELECT m.module, m.content
FROM `modules` m
LEFT JOIN contents c ON m.id = c.module_id
```

...which nicely returns

```
module | content
------   -------
header   This is my header
header   Este es mi encabezado
main     null
footer   This is my footer
```

But now **I need to select only the modules with the `language_id` that maps to 'en-US'**. If I amend my JOINs I lose my "main" module in my result:

```
SELECT m.module, m.content
FROM `modules` m
LEFT JOIN contents c ON m.id = c.module_id
JOIN languages l ON c.language_id = l.id
WHERE l.tag = 'en-US'
```

```
module | content
------   -------
header   This is my header
footer   This is my footer
```

I am *very* new to JOINs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this that would include all records from the modules table which would include records where it doesn't match up in the contents/languages table and limit it to the language you want.

```
SELECT m.module, m.content
FROM `modules` m
LEFT JOIN contents c ON m.id = c.module_id
LEFT JOIN languages l ON c.language_id = l.id
WHERE l.tag = 'en-US' OR l.tag IS NULL
```

Comment: I posted my result, which is what you have plus I added `WHERE ...OR l.tag IS NULL`, which successfully filtered out non-US languages, but I'm still not sure why it works.

Comment: Updated based on your feedback.

Comment: Whilst I have you, would you know how I can have `m.content` return the 'en-US' version if another language is missing? (Since I built the site in English, I know I have ALL of those pieces, but i will be seeding translations from another agency and want to fallback to English when a translation is missing.)

Comment: You might be able to do something using the coalesce function but I am not sure what would all be involved without having a sqlfiddle to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious.  You `JOIN` to `languages` filter out the null rows because there's no matching to the `languages` table.  The combination of `RIGHT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` is bad, but it should work.

```
    SELECT m.module, m.content
    FROM `modules` m
    LEFT JOIN contents c ON m.id = c.module_id
    LEFT JOIN languages l ON c.language_id = l.id
    WHERE l.tag = 'en-US'
```

Comment: Why would you need to do a right join with this?

Comment: If it's just regular `JOIN`, the null rows from the previous `LEFT JOIN` will get filter out because there's no matching `c.language_id = l.id`.

Comment: Weird, `RIGHT JOIN` ended up adding all of my languages, but when i swapped it to `LEFT JOIN` it seems to work. Still playing around with it to make sure.

Comment: I understand that but you get to the same results without needing a right join if you ensure you are starting with the correct table in the select statement.

Comment: @PhilTune That is because of the right join including everything from the languages table. Making into a left join would only include everything from the contents table and with a null value in languages where it doesn't match up with the contents table.

Comment: @JoeW what would you start with? I struggle a lot with these concepts as I'm mostly front-end.

Comment: @PhilTune Put the language condition in `WHERE` to filter language.

Comment: Could you write that out in an answer. I'm plugging these in and still end up missing rows or having way too many rows.

Comment: @PhilTune In this case, `LEFT JOIN` works as @JoeW mentioned.

Comment: @PhilTune I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo, I figured it out but will accept @Joe W et. al. for getting me there.

```
SELECT m.module, m.content
FROM `modules` m
LEFT JOIN contents c ON m.id = c.module_id
LEFT JOIN languages l ON c.language_id = l.id
WHERE l.tag = 'en-US' OR l.tag IS NULL
```

Without the `OR l.tag IS NULL` I was still pulling in rows from non-US languages as well. I don't know why it works, but wanted to post it for posterity or for anyone who wants to yell at me for going about it the wrong way.